# Return a typedef in C

Tags: c, return, typedef

In a .h file I defined:

```
#define PAIR_TYPE(type1, type2)\
    typedef struct {     \     // added \ after edit  
      type1 first;       \     // added \ after edit  
      type2 second;      \     // added \ after edit  
    };     // added ; after edit        
#define MAKE_PAIR(val1, val2) {val1, val2}
PAIR_TYPE(char *, uint32_t) mypair;
mypair foo();
```

In the .c file I used it like this:

```
mypair foo()
{
   mypair p;
   uint32_t bar = calculate();
   p = MAKE_PAIR("normal", target);
   return p;
}
```

However I get this error:

> error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

The line it points is:

```
p = MAKE_PAIR("normal", target);
```

I don't know why it says '{' !!! there is no '{' at that line.

Comment: There is a { on that line once the preprocessor has finished with it (hint: it will replace MAKE_PAIR with...). I suggest you look at the pre-processed output, your compiler almost certainly has an option flag to pre-process only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need more backslashes on the lines after '{'

```
#define PAIR_TYPE(type1, type2)\
  typedef struct {\
    type1 first;\
    type2 second;\
  }
```

Comment: I edited the post. This time I get  error: unknown type name ‘mypair’ which points to   mypair foo();

Comment: Don't put a semicolon in the macrodefinition. Also do't put comment in macros. It will bite you.

Comment: which semicolon you mean? I added the comments only in the post.

Comment: Yes, that one. Normally, you should try to aim at "function style" macros, where the "caller" supplies the terminating ';', if any. That's the whole idea after the "funky do { ... } while(...)" construct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is! But it is hidden from your eyes by the preprocessor magic. Remember, [the preprocessor is evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.8), and you are certainly over-using it.

The preprocessor just does textual substitution, so the code the compiler sees is actually:

```
p = {"normal", target};
```

And that is not valid C syntax. There, see, the '{'.
That syntax is only valid in initialization, not in assignments:

```
mypair a = {"a", 1}; /* ok */
a = {"a", 1}; /* error */
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PAIR_TYPE` macro, you need to get rid of the semicolon at the end so that the name you give for the type is part of the typedef.  Right now, when you do:

```
PAIR_TYPE(char *, uint32_t) mypair;
```

..you get:

```
typedef struct {
  char * first;
  uint32_t second;
}; mypair;
```

..which has a semicolon between the `}` and `mypair` that shouldn't be there.

You will also need to use a cast for your MAKE_PAIR macro to work the way you use it.  Right now, the line:

```
p = MAKE_PAIR("normal", target);
```

..expands to:

```
p = {"normal", target};
```

..which won't work.  But if you add a cast:

```
p = (mypair)MAKE_PAIR("normal", target);
```

..then the expanded line is:

```
p = (mypair){"normal", target};
```

..which can work since the type cast tells the compiler what the fields between the `{` and `}` should be.  Though note that you're setting the `char *` in the first field to point at the literal `"normal"`, not copying the string.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you use c idiom to write macro as shown in the link, you will not have problem that you are experiencing. Please see http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html for details.